# Install Media Player Classic on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, vlc, multimedia

How can I install Media Player Classic on Ubuntu? I want to do this because VLC doesn't read high resolution videos.

Comment: Classic media player is only available for windows. You can try getting it working by [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). I think it would be easier to try to solve your problem within linux. For example did you try any other video players beside vlc? Do you have installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`?

Comment: VLC's own support forum https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=82574 states it can show up to 32 million by 32 million, so something else is going on to prevent VLC from displaying your video. Which codec does it use?

Comment: If you are using integrated Intel GPU consider to check VA settings with `vainfo` and if it is not detected, install with `sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver`. Try to open example video `vlc /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase//Nathan\ Haines\ -\ Ubuntu\ Through\ The\ Years.ogg` and ensure that you have `libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0`.

Comment: @KhaireddineHamdi has already mentioned in his/her answer but I am Not sure, You can install the snap package of media player classic from [here](https://snapcraft.io/install/mpc-hc/ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I had tried it is the right way
https://snapcraft.io/install/mpc-hc/ubuntu

Comment: To install mpc-hc in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu run `sudo snap install mpc-hcl --edge`